# What is the command line option to force OpenSSH to send no-more-sessions@openssh.com

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm using OpenSSH version 7.1p2 (in mobaXterm)

When connecting to a remote SSH server (based on OpenSSH) I sometimes want to disable channel muxing.

I found in the documentation the option to send global request "no-more-sessions@openssh.com" for this:

> Added a no-more-sessions at openssh.com global request extension that is
>   sent from ssh(1) to sshd(8) when the client knows that it will never
>   request another session (i.e. when session multiplexing is disabled).

However, I have not found a command line option in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

META: Although this is a feature of security software (OpenSSH) it isn't clearly a security feature, so its topicality is borderline. It might fit better on superuser or serverfault. But I'll leave that to voters.

Anyway, the code block in `ssh.c` is:

```
/* If we don't expect to open a new session, then disallow it */
if (options.control_master == SSHCTL_MASTER_NO &&
    (datafellows & SSH_NEW_OPENSSH)) {
    debug("Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com");
    packet_start(SSH2_MSG_GLOBAL_REQUEST);
    packet_put_cstring("no-more-sessions@openssh.com");
    packet_put_char(0);
    packet_send();
}
```

As noted in ChangeLog, this is sent if the peer is a new enough version and 'session multiplexing is disabled' (`options.control_master == SSHCTL_MASTER_NO`) which is the default and is changed only if you specify `-M` (up to twice) or use `-o` or a config file to set `controlmaster` (anycase) to a value other than `false` or `no`. So you should specify any option(s) *other than* `-M` or `-o controlmaster`.

Note that even if the peer is old and we can't actually send the option, by default the client still won't actually do session multiplexing (unless hacked). But remember 'forwarding' (often called 'tunneling') which also uses channel multiplexing underneath can still be done as configured by its options *without* any session multiplexing.